# Is it possible to group linear maps by similarity or likelihood that they are identical?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, reference-request

Given a set of linear maps $f: x \rightarrow y$, is there a way to (statistically or otherwise) determine how likely two linear maps are identical even if I do not have enough data to determine $f$?

More details: I have a set of $400,000$ $x \rightarrow y$ pairings. I expect there are actually only $500 - 1,000$ unique linear maps. $x$ is $245*1$ and $y$ is $1*245$.

Even if you don't have a solution, some books, research areas or journals to look into would be helpful. I'm an engineer by training and struggling with mathematicians' technical jargon.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you have $400000$ ordered pairs of vectors. You want to find out how many subsets of those turn out to be part of linear mappings? That sounds intractable...

Comment: It quite possibly is, but I can make my sample simpler. If I had a smaller data set, would there be a way of grouping the maps by similarity?

Comment: If, say, there are $N$ distinct values in the right hand of the $400000$ pairs, and $M$ distinct values in the left, then conceivably there are already parts of $M^N$ distinct linear tranformations there. I think this question is currently too poorly posed for anyone to try a solution. More assumptions need to be added. You say you want to compare two linear maps. That's much easier. If you have two sets of pairs, both of which have $245$ linearly independent members appearing in the left of the pair, then in principle you can tell if their transformation matrices are similar.